# How to Write This Oracle SQL Query ONLY Using Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Table-1 (bk_order_details): order_id, order_line, book_id, quantity, order_price
Table-2 (bk_books): book_id, title
Table-3 (bk_book_topics): book_id, topic_id
```

**Question**:

- Display the book id and title for any books which someone has ordered and the book is categorized as both an SQL book and a database book.
- Use the topic_id to filter for DB and SQL.
- Sort by the book_id.

NOTE: ONLY ALLOW TO USE SUBQUERY.

Thank you in advance! I've tried multiple ways but not getting the desired result.

Comment: Please post the query that you think is closest to the desire answer. We could start from that.

Comment: You will need three IN-Subqueries, one for `bk_order_details` and two for `bk_book_topics`

Comment: If this isn't a homework question, I would be most surprised.

Answer (score 1):

If those topic_id's are numbers, then you would need to know which topic_id numbers you need.
Or it would need an extra table from which those 'SQL' and 'DB' types can be selected.

F.e.

```
Table-4 (bk_topics): topic_id, topic_type
```

In that case, the SQL below just uses joins and a subquery:

```
select 
 b.book_id,
 b.title
from bk_book_topics bt
join 
(
   select topic_id 
   from bk_topics
   where (topic_type = 'SQL' or topic_type = 'DB')
   group by topic_id 
) t on (t.topic_id = bt.topic_id)
join bk_order_details o on (o.book_id = bt.book_id)
join bk_books b on (b.book_id = o.book_id)
group by b.book_id, b.title
order by b.book_id
```

If that topic_id isn't a number, but a varchar that has those types?
And if the use of a subquery is allowed, but not obligated?
Then it can be golfcoded:

```
select 
 b.book_id,
 b.title
from bk_book_topics bt
join bk_order_details o on (o.book_id = bt.book_id)
join bk_books b on (b.book_id = o.book_id)
where bt.topic_id in ('SQL','DB')
group by b.book_id, b.title
order by b.book_id
```